# Unable to change Permalink - Tried tons of tricks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I am using wordpress on godaddy windows hosting. using 4,7,4 version of wordpress.

For some reason permalinks do not work in any mode except of plain, selecting any other structure results in 404 errors at all pages except of home. I know there is a ton of similar questions, but none of the existing solutions does not help (at least all solutions I could find).
.htaccess file is changing when permalink structure is modified, it adds a code that looks as it supposed to be:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Giving different permissions doesn’t do anything.

According to the hosting provider the web server meets all requirements

The website is using woocommerce. Disabling all plugins was tried as well – no effect.

Any other ideas how can I fix this or at least where the problem is? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you changed the links in the database? Before uploading to the server?

Comment: I AM MAKING THE SITE ONLINE ONLY (NO LOCALHOST)

Comment: See my code, use it, hope it will solve your error

Comment: @Exprator , 

Tried with your edited code, but it doesn't work....

I am very much confused, now what to do????

Comment: added a ans give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable mod_rewrite to accept the server to access the formatted URL's

Edit , httpd.conf

```
AllowOverride all
```

Also inside php.ini remove ; from the below extension,

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Comment: I am making the website online only (not on my dektop by using localhost). I am using godaddy windows hosting (plesk)...So i think  mod_rewrite will not be applicable for me...